# Can't compile python program because of jsonschema

Tags: python

I'm trying to compile a python program using auto-py-to-exe, an gui of pyinstaller, but for some reason it can't finish due to this error:

```
File "c:\program files\python37\lib\site-packages\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 786, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req, requirers)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: The 'jsonschema' distribution was not found and is required by the application
```

Any ideas to solve?

Comment: Are you able to import the module separately? If not you will have to install it (https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/)

Comment: When I enter via python console I can import the module that is inside the venv.

Edit: BTW The module is in the requirements.txt along with the remaining modules